# Container Builder Slack Notifications

Tags: google-container-builder

we're testing out CB and part of our requirements is sending messages to Slack.

[This tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/configure-third-party-notifications#preparing_the_slack_application) works great, but it'd be helpful if we could specify the source of the build, so we don't have to click in to the message to see what repo/trigger failed/succeeded.

Is there a variable we can pass to the cloud function in the tutorial? I couldn't find helpful documentation.

Ideally, it would be great if CB had an integration/slack GUI that made these options configurable but c'est la vie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add source information to the slack message by adding a new item to the `fields` list within the `createSlackMessage` function. You need to make sure `title` and `value` are strings.

```
// createSlackMessage create a message from a build object.
const createSlackMessage = (build) => {
  let message = {
   text: `Build \`${build.id}\``,
    mrkdwn: true,
    attachments: [
      {
        title: 'Build logs',
        title_link: build.logUrl,
        fields: [{
          title: 'Status',
          value: build.status
        },{
          title: 'Source',
          value: JSON.stringify(build.source, null, 2)
        }]
      }
    ]
  };
  return message
}
```

You can find more information on build object [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds).